# How to use the input of one function in another function which is inside the former function?

Tags: javascript

Relevant code:

```
         function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
            // converts any string of letters to capitalized format. Eg: LArry becomes Larry.
            let capitalize =  function (string){
                newString = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
                string.slice(-(string.length-1)).toLowerCase();
                return newString;
            };
            let player = playerSelection;
            let computer = computerSelection;

            capitalize(player);
            capitalize(computer);
              
            //capitalize doesn't seem to work as intended
         //...more code
         }
```

I want the inputs of `playRound` to be passed into `capitalize` to capitalize the strings into the required format. But apparently `capitalize` isn't working as intended.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of `capitalize`. I guess you want `player = capitalize(player)`. In other words: You are passing the data just fine, but you are ignoring the function's return value and hence there won't be any noticeable changes.

Comment: ... And how is it intended to work? :)

Comment: Yes! I guess I need to write `playerSelection = capitalize(player);` My program works after doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should work fine, you just need to make sure you are using the value that you `return` from the `capitalise` function, like so:

```
player = capitalize(player);
computer = capitalize(computer);
```